# Average of Sequence Terms

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

Let $a_{n}$ be a sequence such that the average of the first and second terms is 1, the average of the second and third terms is 2, the average of third and fourth terms is 3, and so on. How to find the average of the first and 100th terms?

Answer (score 1):

The given averages tell you that

$$n = \frac12\left(a_n + a_{n+1}\right)$$

for all $n \geqslant 1$. You want to know

$$\frac12\left(a_1 + a_{100}\right) = \frac12\left(a_1 + a_2\right) - \frac12\left(a_2+a_3\right) + \frac12\left(a_3 + a_4\right) - \dotsb -\frac12\left(a_{98} + a_{99}\right) + \frac12\left( a_{99} + a_{100}\right).$$

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches:

1. If there is a single answer then it will work for any values, such as $a_1=0.5, a_2=1.5, a_3=2.5, \ldots, a_{99}=98.5, a_{100}=99.5$ and the answer is clearly $50$.  However this method only gives you a possible answer and so only works if there is a single answer; it would not work if the question was asking for the average of the first term  and 99th term, where there is not a single answer, as $49.5$ is only one of an infinite number of possible answers.
2. The other method is that shown by Daniel Fischer, and you have  $ \frac{a_1 + a_{100} }{2} = \frac{a_1 + a_{2} }{2} - \frac{a_2 + a_{3} }{2} +\frac{a_3 + a_{4} }{2} - \cdots -\frac{a_{98} + a_{99} }{2} + \frac{a_{99} + a_{100} }{2} = \displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{50}(2n-1) - \sum_{i=1}^{49}(2n)$ though you need to be careful with the signs. The fact that this gives you a single solution means you can use method 1 in this case. It would be worth thinking about why this does not work with the average of the first term  and 99th term.